# Imprimir valor de una variable después de una redirección

Tags: php

Estoy usando el api de MailChimp para controlar los mensajes de error y redireccionar a páginas según sea el caso. Eso todo bien, lo que necesito es, al ir a la página correcta, capturar e imprimir con un `echo` el valor del campo email. No sé si queda claro la explicación pero igual dejo los códigos.

El formulario:

Éste busca un validar contrato php que se encarga de verificar a que pagina ir o redireccionar

```
<form action="validar-contrato.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_self">
  <div class="base-form">
    <input type="email" value="" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail" data-pattern="^[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" id="mce-EMAIL">
    <input class="btn-email" type="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
  </div>
</form>
```

Página validar contrato.php

Esta página si todo está bien redirecciona a la página token.php; desde aquí, necesito que cuando sea correcto vaya a esta página (token.php) e imprima con un `echo` el contenido de la variable `$email`

```
<?php  
    if ( ! session_id() ) @ session_start();
    require('mailchimp.php');
    if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])){
        $apiKey = 'codigo api';
        $listID = 'ID API';
        $mailchimp = new MailchimpApi($apiKey, $listID);
        $data_user = array(
            'email' => (isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'')
            //'first_name' => '',
            //'last_name' => ''
        );
        //CODES RESULT
        //200: Suscrito correctamente
        //201: Email no válido
        //214: Ya está suscrito
        $url = 'direccion-contrato.php';
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'acceso';
        $rscode = $mailchimp->subscribe($data_user);
        switch ($rscode) {
            case 200:
                $msg = 'You have successfully subscribed.';
                $url = 'token.php';
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'acceso_token';
                break;
            case 201:
                $msg = 'Please enter valid email address.';
                break;
            case 214:
                $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                break;
            default:
                $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                break;
        }
        echo '<script>alert("'.$msg.'")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$url.'"</script>';
    }

?>
```

Página token.php

```
<div class="correo"><?php echo $email;?></div>
```

Lo cual no puedo lograr que imprime el valor de la variable, nesecito una mano. ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en contrato.php, donde estás haciendo la redirección sin pasar la variable que contiene el email, por lo que el valor se va a perder de una página a otra.

Haces la redirección en JavaScript a partir de la variable `$url` que se usa aquí:

```
    ...
    $url = 'direccion-contrato.php';
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'acceso';
    $rscode = $mailchimp->subscribe($data_user);
    switch ($rscode) {
        case 200:
            $msg = 'You have successfully subscribed.';
            $url = 'token.php';
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'acceso_token';
            break;
    ...
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$url.'"</script>';
    ...
```

Si en lugar de simplemente asignar el valor de la URL "token.php" a la variable `$url` le añades también un parámetro en la dirección, tal que así:

```
   $url = 'token.php?email=' . $data_user["email"];
```

En token.php ya podrás leer el valor del email en el `$_GET`:

```
$email = $_GET["email"];
```

---

Aparte de eso, dos recomendaciones:

- Evita hacer la redirección como lo haces desde JS, podrías dar una mejor experiencia de usuario y hacer el programa más rápido y eficiente usando [`header`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) directamente en PHP.
- Todas las entradas de usuario deben sanearse de alguna forma u otra antes de ser utilizadas en consultas SQL o de escribirlas en el HTML. Por ejemplo, en el contexto que pones, podrías usar [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para protegerte de XSS.